# Verce is not working the deployment - tsconfig path

Tags: next.js, vercel

Guys there is some way that Vercel can understand my tsconfig path?

I have the imports working all good ( the npm run build works and etc )

```
import NavBar from "@/components/nav-bar";
```

here my paths in the tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "@/*": [ "./*" ],
     },
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "@types/*", "hooks/api.jsx", "components/table/mobile-table/index.jsx", "pages/api/[address].js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "swc": true
  }
}
```

Type error: Cannot find module 'components/Cart' or its corresponding type declarations.

But everything I use "@/"

Deploy in the vercel :D

Comment: Fix, change all the files that was .js to .tsx